# join new tuple to first list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

I am newbie to python and don't know how to do this.

I have a list of tuples which represent data and another list which represents header. 
I need a set of combinations into new tuples to look from this.

```
data = [( 1, 'a'),( 2, 'b'),( 3, 'c'),( 4, 'd'),(5, 'e')]
header = ["ID", "MyData"]
```

into this

```
newdata = [("ID", "MyData"),( 1, 'a'),( 2, 'b'),( 3, 'c'),( 4, 'd'),(5, 'e')]
```

please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
data.insert(0, tuple(header))
```

Note that this will modify `data` in-place. You can achieve the same results without modifying data like so:

```
newdata = [tuple(header)]
newdata.extend(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a completely new value, without any temporaries:

```
[tuple(header)] + data
```

Addition of two lists concatenates them. We turn the header, which is a list, into a tuple (since we want a tuple of its data in the final result), and then make a list that contains it, so that we can glue the two lists together.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
data.insert(0,tuple(header))
newdata = data
```